# nav bar is not being showed in html

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am beginner in angular.
I have three component file 1. value component 2. nav component. 3. app.component. I need to bring menu bar using the selector: 'app-value'. the value html is being showed without the menu. How can i show the menu from nav.component.html. My github code https://github.com/ppp3pol/datingapp.git

nav.component.html code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

nav.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

value.component.html code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-value',
  templateUrl: './value.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
})
export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {
  values: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
  }

  getValues() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/values').subscribe( response => {
      this.values = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

}
```

```html
<p *ngFor="let value of values">
    {{ value.id}}, {{value.name}}  
</p>
```

app.component code html and ts code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'BookApp-SPA';
}
```

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>

<h1>
    Myapp App
</h1>
<app-value></app-value>
```

finally my app.module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ValueComponent } from './value/value.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ValueComponent,
      NavComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: add a stackblitz

Comment: please can you help with code

Comment: I have no experience in stackblitz. I have given  the code in Github here ppp3pol/datingapp

Comment: Does your getValues() setting value in values

Comment: Yes values are coming in values. only nav menu is not coming in values while displaying the values

Comment: I solved the problem . I forgot to add <app-nav></app-nav> in app component html